# android login registration using php,mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

hey friends i am developing android login registration system using php and mysql on localhost.. i done coding part but my code content some run-time error when i run my app then it at register screen shows "Invalid username or password or email" that means i am getting jsonresult 0 from php means my data like(name,email,pass) is not passing to php....below is my code

for Register.java

```
public class Register extends Activity {
TextView tvlogin;
EditText etuname,etemail,etpass,etmobno;
Button  userreg;
String name,email,pass;
//  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
int flag=0;

    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/examtime/register.php";
//  private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    //.detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
    //.penaltyLog().build());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    etuname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    etemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    etpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    userreg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
//  etmobno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tvlogin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_login);

    userreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            userReg(v);
        }
    });


}   

public void userReg(View v)
{
    name=etuname.getText().toString();
    email=etemail.getText().toString();
//  mobno=etmobno.getText().toString();
    pass=etpass.getText().toString();
    if(name.equals("") || pass.equals("") || email.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username or password or email must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(name.length() <= 1 || pass.length() <= 1){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    // request authentication with remote server4
    AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
    asyncRequestObject.execute(url, name, pass, email);
}
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", params[2]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", params[3]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Server connection failed",        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Invalid username or password or email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Profile.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", name);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully Registered");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
```

//-------
}

```
and for login.java my mainactivity.java


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView userReg;
Button userLogin;    
EditText et_email,et_pass;
String login_email,login_pass;
String Logurl = "http://10.0.2.2/examtime/login.php";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userReg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Register);
    userLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Login);
    et_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    et_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pword);

userReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userReg(v);

    }
}); 
}

public void userReg(View v)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
}

public void userLogin(View v)
{
    login_email=et_email.getText().toString();
    login_pass=et_pass.getText().toString();
    if(login_email.equals("") || login_pass.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(login_email.length() <= 1 || login_pass.length() <= 1){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    // request authentication with remote server4
    AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
    asyncRequestObject.execute(Logurl, login_email, login_pass);

    startActivity(new Intent(this,Home.class));

}
  private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[1]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", params[2]));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            if(result.equals("") || result == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
            if(jsonResult == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(jsonResult == 1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                intent.putExtra("USERNAME",login_email);
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
    private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        JSONObject resultObject = null;
        int returnedResult = 0;
        try {
            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
            returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnedResult;


    }
}
```

and my php code is
index.php

```
    <?php

require_once 'include/user.php';

$username = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$username = $_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
$password = $_POST['pass'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
}

// Instance of a User class
$userObject = new User();

// Registration of new user
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email)){
$hashed_password = md5($password);
$json_registration = $userObject->createNewRegisterUser($username, $hashed_password, $email);

echo json_encode($json_registration);
}

// User Login
if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && empty($email)){
$hashed_password = md5($password);  
$json_array = $userObject->loginUsers($username, $hashed_password);

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

}

?>

and my User.php

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

class User{

private $db;
private $db_table = "stud";

public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DbConnect();
}

public function isLoginExist($username, $password){     

    $query = "select * from " . $this->db_table . " where name = '$username' AND pass = '$password' Limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
        return true;
    }       
    mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
    return false;       
}

public function createNewRegisterUser($username, $password, $email){

    $query = "insert into stud (name, pass, email) values ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);
    if($inserted == 1){
        $json['success'] = 1;                                   
    }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
    }
    mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
    return $json;
}

public function loginUsers($username, $password){

    $json = array();
    $canUserLogin = $this->isLoginExist($username, $password);
    if($canUserLogin){
        $json['success'] = 1;
    }else{
        $json['success'] = 0;
    }
    return $json;
}
```

}

?>

i know i am missing something i try to explain it sorry for bad English and i am also new to android and also new in stack overflow

Comment: I would assume that this is running on an emulator because of the IP address, so did you try checking if your emulator can access the server? or the URL by directly running the URL in the emulator's browser? and your login/registration php code is in your `index.php`. but in your java code it's pointing to the `login.php` and `register.php`

Comment: yes when i put (http://10.0.2.2/examtime/include) to my emulator browser i am access the Directory.wait i try to point login/registration  code to index.php thanks

Answer (score 1):

tbh it was too much code for me to read through all of this, but I think I know what you want.
first check if Name already exists:

```
<?php>

$text = $_POST["text1"];
$db = @new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.de", "...", "...", "...");
if($db->connect_error){
    die("<pre>".$db->connect_error."</pre>");
}

$num = $sql->num_rows; 
$sql = $db->query("SELECT name FROM Rangliste");
$num = $sql->num_rows; 
if($num > 0){
    while($row = $sql->fetch_object()){
        if($row->name == $text){
            echo("Name already exists!");
        }else{
            echo("Name accepted!");
        }

    }
}
```

and so on... connect it with your java